# dynamic change url in $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, get

I need to dynamic change url in `$http.get` with data from other `$http.get`

JSON "datas":

```
[{ "name" : "John" }, {"name" : "Anna"}]
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        this.getDatas = function () {
            var datas = $http.get('urldatas', {cache: false});
            return $q.all({datas});
        };
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.loadData = function () {
            var promise = service.getDatas();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
                console.log($scope.datas);
            });
        };
    vm.loadPackages = function () {
      var url = 'url2' + 'QQQ' + $scope.datas.name;

    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        console.log($scope.myWelcome);
            })
        };
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="name in datas">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="vm.loadPackages()"></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to dynamically change URL in `$http.get` in `loadPackages`, by values from `getDatas`, and from HTML. The button calls the function and gives data to the url, but my code doesn't work, `var url = 'url2' + 'QQQ' + $scope.datas.name;` returns `url2QQQundefindet` in console.

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: try using interceptors

Comment: `return $q.all({datas});` isn't valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `$scope.datas` is an array. U cant directly access like `$scope.datas.name`. If you knw exact index value then simply access based on index `$scope.datas[index].name`. Please find the code snippet below.

In html, im passing respective row to the function.

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="name in datas">
   <td>{{name.name}}</td>
   <td><button ng-click="vm.loadPackages(name)"></button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in controller i can get name,

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        this.getDatas = function () {
            var datas = $http.get('urldatas', {cache: false});
            return $q.all({datas});
        };
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.loadData = function () {
            var promise = service.getDatas();
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
                console.log($scope.datas);
            });
        };
    vm.loadPackages = function (obj) {
      var url = 'url2' + 'QQQ' + obj.name;

    $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        console.log($scope.myWelcome);
            })
        };
```